# Spring AOP - start method from execution using @Before advice

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Is it possible to execute method org.document.DocumentService.addDocument(..) in documentAccessCounter method

Code :

```
 @Before("execution(* org.document.DocumentService.addDocument(..))")
    public void documentAccessCounter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can control the invocation of the target method on your own with the Around advice. 
The following snippet is from the Spring documentation -> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

```
@Around("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService()")
public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    // start stopwatch
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
    // stop stopwatch
    return retVal;
}
```

This allows you to may decide to not invoke the method, do some execution time measurment or whatever you like.